# If $\widehat{M}$ is a free $\widehat{R}$-module of rank $n$ then $M$ has a generating set of $n$ elements as an $R$-module.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, formal-completions

With reference to my last question [If $\widehat{M}$ is a free $\widehat{R}$-module, then $M$ is a free $R$-module, $R$ is a Zariski ring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755630) I want to ask the following question.

> Let $R$ be a Zariski ring with $I$-adic topology, $I \subset J(R)$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module such that the $I$-adic completion $\widehat{M}$ is a free $\widehat{R}$-module of rank $n$. Then how can I show that $M$ has a generating set of $n$ elements as an $R$-module.

I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $n$ generators of $\widehat M$, $x_1,...,x_n$.

Let $y_1,...,y_n$ denote their image in $M/IM$. Then, $y_1,...,y_n$ generate $M/IM$.

Indeed, $\widehat M\to M/IM$ is surjective ($M\to \widehat M\to M/IM$ is surjective), so if $z\in M/IM$, let $w$ be any antecedent, $w= \sum_i \lambda_i x_i$ implies that $z =\sum_i \mu_i y_i$, with $\mu_i$ the image of $\lambda_i$ under $\widehat R\to R/I$.

But now since $I\subset J(R)$, Nakayama's lemma tells you that any antecedents of $y_1,...,y_n$ generate $M$ (here, use the assumption that $M$ is finitely generated)

Comment: About the projection map: are you talking about $\widehat M\to M/IM$ ? If so, note that $\lambda_i\neq \mu_i$. $\mu_i$ is the $R/I$-projection of $\lambda_i$ - I'm not using that $\widehat M$ is $R$-linearly generated by $n$ elements, that much is certainly wrong in general. I don't understand your other doubts : if $M/IM$ is generated as an $R$-module by $n$ elements, and $M$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module, then Nakayama's lemma applies, with no conditions (other than $I\subset J(R)$)

Comment: Can you elaborate how this holds "$w= \sum_i \lambda_i x_i$ implies that $z =\sum_i \mu_i y_i$, with $\mu_i$ the image of $\lambda_i$ under $\widehat R\to R/I$. "

Comment: That's essentially the definition of the $\widehat R$ action on $\widehat M$: if $x= (x_n)_n \in \widehat R, y= (y_n)\in \widehat M$, $xm$ is defined to be $(x_ny_n)$ (and then you check that this is a module structure etc. ) In particular, $(xm)_1 = x_1m_1$, so here $(\lambda_ix_i)_1 = (\lambda_i)_1 (x_i)_1 = \mu_i y_i$

Comment: Thanks for this discussion.